# SimpleMessageListenerContainer Amazon SQS Pollinterval

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am using Spring Cloud library to poll SQS. How can I set poll interval?

```
@Bean
@Primary
public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().
            withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider()).
            withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration()).
            build();
}


@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.queue")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler());
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
}


@Bean
public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler() {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
    QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
    return queueMessageHandler;
}


@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("oaoQueueExecutor");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call setWaitTimeOut(N) function of the base class AbstractMessageListenerContainer in package org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener. N is the long poll timeout in seconds. 
For example if you want to wait for 5 sec before it returns, use below line of code in your queueMessageHandler() function. The default is 1 sec if you don't call this function. The maximum long polling timeout is 20 sec, so the max you can give to this function is 20 which means "wait for 20 seconds"

```
simpleMessageListenerContainer.setWaitTimeOut (5);
```

The source code is here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java

```
/**
     * Configures the wait timeout that the poll request will wait for new message to arrive if the are currently no
     * messages on the queue. Higher values will reduce poll request to the system significantly.
     *
     * @param waitTimeOut
     *         - the wait time out in seconds
     */
    public void setWaitTimeOut(Integer waitTimeOut) {
        this.waitTimeOut = waitTimeOut;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Raj. What is the difference between this and the long poll interval that is set as part of SQS configuration in AWS console ?

Comment: Good question. The help says "The maximum amount of time that a long polling receive call will wait for a message to become available before returning an empty response.". My understanding is if you set 15 seconds as max in console, you can choose between 1 and 15 in the Java client.

Comment: Thank you , I’ll test it out.

Comment: @PunterVicky According to AWS docs a positive value in poll requests wins over queue attribute:
For the WaitTimeSeconds parameter of the ReceiveMessage action, a value set between 1 and 20 has priority over any value set for the queue attribute ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html)

Comment: @Raj Are you suggesting extending AbstractMessageListenerContainer? Or accessing SimpleMessageListenerContainer through Spring application context and modifying the setting?

Comment: Note, that by default the timeout is set to 20 seconds in Spring Cloud's code  starting version 2.0.0, see this issue for details: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/319